# Python error ("RecursionError") after updating QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, error

After updating from QGIS 3.12 Bucuresti to QGIS 3.14.16 with OSGeo4W, when opening QGIS (with or without a project), I get a Python warning "RecursionError" (sic!, QGIS says warning, Python says error). What does it mean and what do I need to do about it? I searched for solutions on the net, but I am less-than-rookie in Python, it gets technical  real quick, and I no longer see the forest for the trees.

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 777, in _import
              new_path = os.environ['PATH']
              File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
              value = self._data[self.encodekey(key)]
              File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\os.py", line 744, in encodekey
              return encode(key).upper()
             RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Yes, it's only a warning, but warnings tend to come back later to bite us, so I'd like to not let it pass unnoticed.

Comment: When and where do you get that error message?

Comment: @BERA ah yes, I should have mentioned it happens at QGIS application startup. There's no reproducible code for this, I believe. I'll add that info to the question.

Comment: @til_b I added "when opening QGIS (with or without a project)" to the question. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a QGIS bug that was already fixed, see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38720 . Don't know when the fix will be released, but no need to take further action except wait and update QGIS.